# Insert by ignoring Row Number ()

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables A and B
Both the table have Row Number field

**Table A**

```
RowNumber   Id    Name    Address
1           1     ABC      India
2           2     XYZ      Australia
```

**Table B**

```
RowNumber Id  Name  Address
1          3  ABC    India
```

I need to insert the Table B's value at the end of Table A. As the Table A is holding RowNumber field so the Table B's value is not coming at the end of Table A's value, it is displaying after the First row of Table A. But I need the Value at the End of Table A. Please help

Comment: Why you persist the RowNumber in a column? You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` function

Comment: Tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as "the end of Table A".

Comment: @GordonLinoff Some would say "the end of Table A" happens when that table gets dropped :-)

Answer (score 0):

Give an extra column value to just for the sake of sorting.

**Query**

```
select t.[RowNUmber], t.[Id], [Name], [Address] from(
    select [RowNumber], [Id], [Name], [Address], 0 as [sortby]
    from [TableA]
    union all
    select [RowNumber], [Id], [Name], [Address], 1 as [sortby]
    from [TableB]
)t
order by t.[sortby], t.[RowNumber];
```

Comment: Without using Order by is there is any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you order by ID then you will get the expected result in the selection but for the insertion you have to make `RowNumber` column as `IDENTITY` then it will insert next record with `RowNumber 3,4,5....so on

```
SELECT RowNumber,   Id,    Name,    Address from TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT RowNumber,   Id,    Name,    Address from TableB
ORDER BY ID
```

**TRY** to insert in the following way and give the max value of TableA so that it will generate number after that:

```
INSERT INTO TableA 
SELECT (row_number() OVER (ORDER BY rownumber)+2) AS n,
    id,
    name,
    address
FROM TableB
```

Comment: I can not make that column as Identity. My objective is to Insert the value with the Row Number value But I can not use order By clause . Is there is any way where Row number value can be updated or ignored ?

Comment: Try the updated one while inserting, if you found it suitable.

Comment: I tried the following query.
INSERT INTO TableA 
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY rownumber)+2 n,
    id,
    name,
    address
FROM TableB


It is giving me following error :  Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.